# OpsGenie CloudWatch Integration not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, opsgenie

For some reason, the opsgenie Amazon SNS integration is working fine but the issue is that for every alert the alias is different which prevents opsgenie from de-duplicating. On the other hand, the Cloudwatch integration does provide a proper alias but i dont know why it's not able to receive any alarms/alerts whatsoever from aws cloudwatch, even if i try to send/publish a test message i get literally nothing!

can anyone please help, i've been stuck on this for 3 days now!

Thanks alot in advance for any help!